# In mule, how to invoke a class method via jmx

Tags: quartz-scheduler, mule, jmx

I use quartz to schedule a custom job to run daily, at a specific time.

However, the machine running mule may be down during that specific scheduled run time, and the custom job cannot get run on that day. So, I wonder if it is possible that I can use jmx to invoke the quartz custom job's execute() method manually.

Comment: If jobs are so critical to be be executed at the scheduled time, then Why don't you try for clustered environment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to use a `<composite-source>` to allow your flow to be triggered both by Quartz and HTTP. That way you can manually trigger it with a simple `curl` invocation.

Something like:

```
<flow name="dualTriggerFlow">
    <composite-source>
        <quartz:inbound-endpoint ...>
        ...
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
       <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="8081" path="/jobs/myjob/trigger" />
    </composite-source>
    ...
```

Of course it depends on what type of Quartz job you're executing. I'm assuming an `event-generator-job`.